# wpf style is not loading after changing background in runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two grids inside a grid.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid x:Name="grid1" MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.Column="0">
        <TextBlock  FontSize="50" Text="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid x:Name="grid2"  MouseLeftButtonDown="Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown" Grid.Column="1">
        <TextBlock FontSize="50" Text="2" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

I am using this method for adding style to grids in runtime.

```
private void StyleGrid()
{
    var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();

    Style myS = new System.Windows.Style();

    Setter setter1 = new Setter();
    setter1.Property = Grid.BackgroundProperty;
    setter1.Value = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#3F3F46");
    myS.Setters.Add(setter1);


    Setter setter = new Setter();
    setter.Property = Grid.BackgroundProperty;
    setter.Value = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#54545C");

    Trigger trigger = new Trigger();
    trigger.Property = Grid.IsMouseOverProperty;
    trigger.Value = true;
    trigger.Setters.Add(setter);
    myS.Triggers.Add(trigger);

    grid1.Style = myS;
    grid2.Style = myS;
}
```

I am calling this method after InitializeComponent method. Everything works fine.

And this is MouseLeftButtonDown event for grids.

```
     private void Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    Grid senderGr = sender as Grid;

    StyleGrid();
    var converter = new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter();

    var brush = (Brush)converter.ConvertFromString("#007ACC");


    senderGr.Background = brush;
}
```

This method must change sender grid's background color and must change  style of other grid. But it is not changing style.

You can download and test project from SkyDrive if you have Microsoft account. Thanks.
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=89FD450CC0CC74DA!168

Comment: Why should Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown() change the style?

Comment: OK.Good question. Then, Why should you add comment?

Comment: :D :D You misunderstood me, I just asked this because StyleGrid() wasnt in this method before, so the method couldnt change any style.

Comment: :D:D OOO....Yes, I got it.  Question was updated. StyleGrid() method in Grid_MouseLeftButtonDown event.

Comment: Lets say if you click on grid2, it changes its background color. And if you click then on grid1, grid2 should change its background color back to normal, but it doesnt, right?

Comment: @FlorianGl Yes, exactly.

Comment: You shouldnt use Triggers/Setters on a property and change the value of this property manuelly, thats not working.

Comment: What must i do? What is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the Background directly will always override the defined Style. WPF uses a set order in which it determines the actual value of a Dependency Property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx)

To achieve your result just clear the set values in your StyleGrid() method:

```
private void StyleGrid()
{
    grid1.ClearValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty);
    grid2.ClearValue(Grid.BackgroundProperty);
...
```